# hasOne is null condition for cakephp find()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm dealing with some pretty bad inherited code, and there is a query pulling events from a table. The events model has `$hasOne = array('blocked');` - my goal is to only return all events that do not have an entry in the blocked table. Despite the $hasOne being set cake is still querying the blocked events table separately so I can't ever use the fields as conditions.

The query itself is already inside of a `'contains' => ...` so using  `'joins' => ...` to manually force a join isn't working.

Updated: here is the find query as it exists now:

```
$params = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Restaurant.id' => $id,
        'Restaurant.inactive' => 0, 'Restaurant.deleted' => 0,
        'Restaurant.bkwindow <=' => (strtotime($criteria['Restaurant']['date']) - strtotime("today"))/86400
    ),
    'fields' => array(),
    'contain' => array(
        'Experience' => array(
            'Experience_blocking'
        )
    )
);
```

I need the Experience table to only return results that do NOT have entries in the Experience_blocking table. Experience is set with the $hasOne of Experience_blocking but it never works, it always queries it as a containable.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't show much code I'll try to guess what your problem is, and be verbose. You can't do what you want using Containable behavior.

For a more verbose answer see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8709438/234594)